# How to disable or hide WhatsApp Web Sidebar?

Tags: whatsapp

I have tried the solution provided [here][1]

[1]: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119105/how-can-i-toggle-or-shrink-the-whatsapp-web-sidebar which doesn't seem to work now. Could be due to the changes over the years.

Is there way to hide or close the sidebar that shows the contacts and conversations? Just surprised that WhatsApp doesn't offer this option directly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable/hide the sidebar, open Inspect tools and search id="side" and select its parent div and on elements.style write the following css:

> display : none

If you want to unhide the sidebar just remove css or deselect it.

Comment: Thank you, works well. 

But would have to repeat the process every time WhatsApp reloads, logs out or refreshes. So looking for a way that works upfront may be through some code changes using an chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension, it seems works great
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/whatsapp-web-sidebar-togg/meoojinhimemkeehlhbojjhnchhgpbak